# Скрипт PS для изменения поля руководитель в AD

Tags: powershell

всем привет. Есть парсер из xml файла и скрипт к нему:

```
$AllUSer=(Select-Xml -Path C:\erpxml\erp.xml -XPath '//d:СтрокиТаблицы' -Namespace @{d='d';m='m'}).Node.element.Where{$_.Сотрудник }.Сотрудник 
    foreach ($user1st in $AllUSer)
{
        $managerRR=(Select-Xml -Path C:\erpxml\erp.xml -XPath '//d:СтрокиТаблицы' -Namespace @{d='d';m='m'}).Node.element.Where{$_.Сотрудник -eq $user1st}.РуководительСотрудник
    $managerFF=(Select-Xml -Path C:\erpxml\erp.xml -XPath '//d:СтрокиТаблицы' -Namespace @{d='d';m='m'}).Node.element.Where{$_.Сотрудник -eq $managerRR}.ЛогинАД

    Write-Host $user1st
    Write-Host $managerRR

         $managerGG=$managerFF.Split("\")[-1]
         Write-Host $managerGG
         $managerHH=Get-ADUser -Identity $managerGG | fl DistinguishedName
         Write-Host  $managerHH



    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter 'displayName -like $user1st' -Properties *
    Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$managerHH}

}
```

$managerHH отдает верные данные.

$user открывает юзера

Но при попытки выполнения я получаю вот такую ошибку:

Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Micros
oft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
Set-ADUser : Недопустимый тип "System.Management.Automation.PSObject".
Имя параметра: manager
строка:19 знак:9
+         Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$managerHH}
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (CN=username...C=demenname,DC=loc:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser

почему не получается записать $managerHH в поле manager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kirill Pashkov, спасибо, но к сожалению такая конструкция не работает, я пробовал. 
Спасибо товарищу **KDE777** с *cyberforum.ru*
Проблема заключалась, цитирую:
aka @**KDE777**:

> "Так не делают. fl (Formst-List) предназначен только для вывода на экран. Корректный вариант: $managerHH = (Get-ADUser -Identity $managerGG).DistinguishedName"

Всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Поле `Manager` принимает на вход объект типа `<ADUser>`, в то время как вы  передаете форматированный `PSObject` в составе `Hash` таблицы.

Попробуйте заменить

```
$managerHH=Get-ADUser -Identity $managerGG | fl DistinguishedName
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$managerHH}
```

На

```
$managerHH=Get-ADUser -Identity $managerGG
Set-ADUser -Identity $user -Replace @{manager=$managerHH.SamAccountName}
```